# Inheritance with the Entity Framework Code first, field repeats in table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco

```
Class GeneralRequest 
{    
String BaseProperty { get set}
}

RapidRequest: GeneralRequest
{
Bool IsSignRequired { get set}    
}

BackRequest : GeneralRequest
{
Bool IsSignRequired { get set}    
}

OtherRequest: GeneralRequest
{   
String Note   { get set}   
}
```

This is the structure of codes I have in my project.

The property IsSignRequired  comes in BackRequest and RapidRequest but it need not come in OtherRequest.

But when I generate database using this codes.

I get property IsSignRequired comes twice in my table as
IsSignRequired1 IsSignRequired2 etc.

How can I specify that it is only neded once in my table

Comment: What is your mapping configuration?

Comment: Where is the `OtherRequest` **property** in your model? I see the `OtherRequest` **class** only.

Comment: it is IsSignRequired proprty.Let me edit the post thanks roman

Comment: Thanks roman  for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You either need to have another intermediate class that `RapidRequest` and `BackRequest` inherits from that defines an inherited `IsSignRequired`, or use the `ColumnAttribute` to force the name of the field.  Another option is to use `TablePerType` inheritance, but that will generate separate tables for unique fields for each subclass.

EntityFramework is doing this because the field is declared independently on the subclasses. By default each subclass will get unique copies of any fields defined in that class, only inherited fields will be shared.